# How to copy databases automatically from one server to another in efficient way (not backup and restore)

Tags: sql-server, database, server

every once in a while I need to move a database from one server (QA) to another (production )
until now I used to perform backup on one server copy to the other server and then restore it... 
is there a way to do it more efficiently?
maybe an automated job?
mirror? replication?
I'm searching for one-two clicks solution..
tnx.

I already made an automated script that does all of the following:
1)backup.
2)zip.
3)copy.
4)unzip. 
5)restore.

Comment: Replication is not the same as a backup, however similar. Replication, be it snapshot, merge or transactional, will "stream" data to the subscribing database. Unless you are using bi-directional replication, the subscriber must remain read-only. Backup/Restore is relatively low maintenance whereas replication can be a headache when it breaks.

Comment: Consider taking a compressed backup and to avoid the zip/unzip. Seems a bit odd to me that one would copy QA to production.

Comment: How large is the database?

Comment: I don't think there is a 1 to 2 click solution.  One way is to right-click database;  Tasks --> Copy Database...  You have to click more than twice though to set source and target server information.

Comment: OT for SO - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) at best. Even then, it is probably too broad and too subjective.

Answer (score 2):

Could you possible create an SSIS package (using the Transfer Database Task+ Transfer SQL Server Objects) that you can execute when you need it? You could create a 'template' package and use it for further use with just changing the connections. 
See this blog post for some more details:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2064/transfer-database-task-and-transfer-sql-server-objects-task-in-ssis/

From the link above:

> **Transfer Database Task:** The Transfer Database Task is used to move a database to another SQL Server instance or create a copy on the same
>   instance (with different database name). This task works in two modes
>   [...]:
>
> **Offline** : In this mode, the source database is detached from the source server after putting it in single user mode, copies of the mdf,
>   ndf and ldf files are moved to specified network location [...]
>
> **Online** : In this mode, the task uses SMO to transfer the database objects to the destination server. In this mode, the database is
>   online during the copy and move operation, but it will take longer as
>   it has to copy each object from the database individually [...].
>
> **Transfer SQL Server Objects Task** The Transfer SQL Sever Objects task is used to transfer one or more SQL Server objects to a different
>   database, either on the same or another SQL Server instance. This
>   allows you to select different types of objects you want to transfer.
>   You can select tables, views, stored procedures, user defined
>   functions etc. [...]

Not sure what it would take to make this package transferable among the different databases you may need to copy, but maybe it's worth exploring.
Good luck! :)